# What's the best way to find if a SQL record ceased to exist in a subsequent time period

Tags: sql

How can I generate a list of items that existed in one time period, but don't exist in a following time period. For example, a list of items that existed in January 2019, but did not appear in February 2019. I posted an idea of the sample query below, but I don't know how to approach this.

```
select period, item
from table
where period = 'February 2019'
and item (exists) in period -1
and item (does not exist) in period
```

Sample Data would be as follows (if there were three records, for example)

```
Period         Item
January 2019   Bob
January 2019   Steve
January 2019   Phil
February 2019  Steve
February 2019  Phil
```

Desired results would be as follows:

```
Period         Item
January 2019   Steve
```

Thank you for the help.

Comment: Please show sample data and desired results.

Comment: Hopefully the edit added some clarity

Comment: Are your dates really stored as e.g. February 2019?

Comment: @SalmanA They're stored as 2019-01-01, 2019-02-01, 2019-03-01, etc.

Comment: To clarify the above comment, they're formatted as yyyy-mm-dd

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on your sample query, you should be able to use aggregation:

```
select item
from table
where period in ('February 2019', 'January 2019')
group by item
having min(period) = max(period) and
       min(period) = 'January 2019';
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use MONTH(yourdate) to get the month number and use that to get the desired results.

```
  DECLARE @Month INT
  SET @Month=1

  SELECT * FROM 
   (SELECT * FROM #table WHERE month_number=@Month)current_period
    LEFT JOIN
   (SELECT * FROM #table WHERE month_number=@Month+1)following_period
  ON
  current_period.item=following_period.item
  WHERE
  following_period.item IS NULL
```

The SELECT after LEFT JOIN can be modified to Period_ID>@Month to include all the following periods.